# Are Quorums necessary in a SQL Server Distributed Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I am creating a SQL Server 2016/2019 Distributed Availability Group, which will host 2 AGs (one at one location and another at a different location). Do I need to create a Quorum for each of the 2 WSFC that will host an Availability Group?

Thank you. J

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to create a Quorum for each of the 2 WSFC that will host an Availability Group?

If you're wanting HA, then yes as you'll be forced to use clustering of some type (Windows or Linux). If you just want DR or scaled reads then no, you can use read-scale availability groups on each side... but that's going to be a huge pain to keep working properly as it's all manual.